# Есть ли необходимость использовать пункты списка для навигации при использовании flexbox?

Tags: html, html5

Я видела довольно много примеров, когда раньше для создания меню навигации использовали список. Но есть ли в этом необходимость, если использовать flexbox? Он же позволяет привести навигацию к такому же самому виду.

Или в использовании списков есть ещё какой-то смысл?

Т.е. могу ли я просто писать так?

```html
   <nav>
     <a>Пунт 1</a>
     <a>Пунт 2</a>
     <a>Пунт 3</a>
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете. Использование списков ul не является обязательным, но код с их применением по назначению является более читабельным, корректным и профессиональным, не важно flexbox это или grid (это никак не связано). Тут действует простое правило: есть список - желательно использовать ul. Примеры списков: меню (список ссылок), галлерея (список изображений), различные блоки  и тд...